# Get value of hidden column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have added columns dynamically in kendo ui grid. I have added a hidden column in the grid as below.

```
($(document.getElementById(divId))).kendoGrid({
            columns: columns,
            dataSource: masterData,
            pageable: {
                pageSize: 10
            },
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            scrollable: true,
            change: onChange,            
            selectable: "multiple",
            dataBound: RowDataBound,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "MasterColID"
                }
            }
        }).data("kendoGrid");
```

On the click of the row , I am trying to get the value of the MasterColID in the onchange event as below

```
var dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[this.select().closest("tr").index()];
var masterID = dataItem["ID"]; //or dataItem.MasterColID;
```

But everytime I check the varaible masterID i undefined.

Please anyone can help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: got this working was some issue in the configuration from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var gridData = $('.k-grid').data("kendoGrid");
var selectedRowData = gridData.dataItem($('.k-grid').find("tr.k-state-selected"));

alert(selectedRowData.MasterColID);
```

Answer (score -1):

Telerik Grid column:

```
columns.Bound(model => model.Id).ClientTemplate("#= cba.GridActions(data) #").Title("").Width(100).Sortable(false);
```

JS function:

```
function GridActions(data) {
    var MasterColID = data.MasterColID;
    ...
}
```